# What is the meaning of "is_synthetic" in watchdog?

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I was working with Python's watchdog and I came across `is_synthetic` and I didn't find any decent explanation of it. What is its purpose?

Comment: A synthetic event is one that came from something other than a filesystem change.  There are ways to inject other events into the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Synthetic events**: They are actions generated by the observer, which may well be stopping, pausing or resuming the observation of the directory.

**Not Synthetic Events**: These are the actual changes to the file system, such as deleting, modifying, or creating a file.

[image]

The **purpose** of these synthetic events is to give you information about the observer's actions. It allows you to have additional relevant information.

I hope with this you can understand better :)